# Bootstrap Datetimepicker not working with Master Pages

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap to make my form. I am unable to use bootstrap datetimepicker in my project. Can master page be a problem?

Please help me out here.

Jquery and Sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>   

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function () {
                    $("#dp").click(function () {
                        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                    })
                })
            });
        </script>
```

ASPX Code:

```
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                                <span id="dp" class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any element with id datetimepicker1 in your pasted aspx code. Please check you have element with id datetimepicker1

Comment: Mohsin, Thankyou so much for pointing out that for me, i was such an idiot to miss such a small thing! It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

use var date_input = $('#<%=date.ClientID%>'); and set clientmodeid to static.